# Dúvida com tabela em div css

Tags: html, css

Estou montando uma tabela em div e css, o problema e que preciso que a div div-table-row tenha o tamanho as outras divs. porém ela fica dando uma quebra de linha. Como resolvo isso?

Segue meu código:

```css
.div-table{
                display:table;
                width: 502px;
            }
            .div-table-row{
                display:table-row;
                width: 50%;
            }
            .div-table-col{border: 1px solid #484848;
                display:table-cell; 
                padding: 5px; 
                width: 50%;
            }
```

```html
<div class='div-table'>
                    <div class='div-table-row'>
                        <div class='linha font-2'>nosdaasdme nodasdasdme nosdasdasdsdme</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='div-table-row'>
                        <div class='div-table-col font-1'>(ID: ) - QTD:</div>
                        <div class='div-table-col font-1'>R$</div>
                        <div class='div-table-col font-1'>MOUSE</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Porque criar uma tabela com divs? Sendo que já existe table e ,tr, th e td pra isto? Siga essa regra básica, tabelas são pra dados tabulares e divs pra dividir e organizar o layout. Me parece que você quer montar uma lista de dados tabulares então `<table>` já lhe atende. Esta história de que usar tabela é errado foi mal explicada, na verdade é errado usar pra layouts de páginas, mas pra mostrar dados tabulares semelhantes ao Excel é perfeitamente aceitavel.

Comment: na verdade estou montando um layout, e usei isso como exemplando entendeu.

Comment: A estrutura visual me parece de dados tabulares, acho que talvez você não tenha entendido isto. Dados tabulares é o esquema que todas colunas e linhas seguem o mesmo tamanho proporcional uns aos outros. De uma pesquisada no termo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se vai estruturar dados tabulares então use `<table>` mesmo, esta história que provavelmente você deve ter ouvido de alguém que *"usar tabelas é errado"* é "mal contada", na verdade o problema é usar tabelas pra montar o layout da página, como menus, colunas principais e rodapé, mas se quer exibir dados semelhantes a planilhas então `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<th>`, `<tbody>` e `<td>` são seus amigos, use-os.

```css
.minha-tabela {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.minha-tabela, .minha-tabela td {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="minha-tabela">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">nosdaasdme nodasdasdme nosdasdasdsdme</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>(ID: ) - QTD:</td>
        <td>R$</td>
        <td>MOUSE</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Também existe uma tag chamada [`<caption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) acaso você queira que a primeira linha na verdade seja um "titulo" pra tabela, assim:

```css
.minha-tabela {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.minha-tabela td, .minha-tabela caption {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.minha-tabela caption {
     border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="minha-tabela">
<caption>Titulo</caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>produto</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>(ID: ) - QTD:</td>
        <td>R$</td>
        <td>MOUSE</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Opção 01

```
.div-table{ display:table; width: auto;}
.div-table-row{display:table-row;width: 33%;  /*se quiser pode colocar auto neste também*/}
.div-table-col{border: 1px solid #484848;display:table-cell;padding: 5px;width: 33%;}
```

Opção 02

```
.div-table{ display:table; width: 33%;}
.div-table-row{display:table-row;width: 33%;}
.div-table-col{border: 1px solid #484848;display:table-cell;padding: 5px;width: 33%;}
```

Dica:

Tente sempre distribuir a largura em ambas as divs para não distorcer, tente utilizar o [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com),
ele permite criar layouts responsivos sem complicação

Comment: não deu certo amigo

Comment: tente executar seu código no site http://codepen.io/pen/